# Why does boost not support symmetric coroutine?

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine

In the (deprecated) `boost::coroutines`, both asymmetric and symmetric coroutine are supported.
However, in the latest `boost::coroutines2`, only asymmetric is supported.

[This list](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2015/06/223701.php) states that symmetric coroutine is better represented by `boost::context::execution_context`. However, from [the document of execution_context](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/ecv2.html), execution_context is again deprecated.

So, is symmetric coroutine(or a similar semantics) supported by the current boost library? If boost refuses to provide such an implementation, what's the reason?

I know from [the boost doc](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/symmetric_coroutines.html) that asymmetric coroutine and symmetric coroutine have the same expressive power, but it's inconvenient for me to waste time building a symmetric abstraction on top of asymmetric one.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that boost::context provides `callcc` and `continuation`, which is sufficient to use as a symmetric coroutine.